# Crashing on layout.main

Tags: android, android-layout

I have released my app to Market yesterday and I get a strange crash report telling me that it doesnt find the layout.main. If the layout wouldnt exist, I would wouldnt be able to start the app on my own device. Which is not the case. Too bad the report doesnt tell which device or Android version it is running on.
Maybe someone can download my app (mytaxicontrol - it's free) and tell me under which conditions its crashing or has an idea what the problem could be?

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mytaxicontrol/com.mytaxicontrol.MyTaxiControlActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030004
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030004
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1869)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
at com.mytaxicontrol.MyTaxiControlActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

Comment: Do you have all your layouts in res\layout? Perhaps one or more of them is only in a qualified folder such as res\layout-port?

Comment: Try to do a clean of the project. Sometimes the R file refers to old values of resources. The cleanup fixes this.

Comment: I have 2 main.xml, one in layout-norm and the 2nd in layout-large. I have cleaned the project before uploading it.

Comment: I think the device downloaded the app may be a small resolution device. Check my answer

Comment: retagged, removed java (java is a [kinda] supertipe of android so it is redundant), changed layout to android-layout to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the manifest you should have added this because you do not need support for small screens devices as layout is not mentioned.

```
   <supports-screens
                android:smallScreens="false"
                android:normalScreens="true" 
                android:largeScreens="true"
                android:anyDensity="true" />
```

And your layout folder name should be

```
layout-normal
layout-large
```

Comment: "-normal" isn't required. "layout" and "layout-large" are enough :)

Comment: I dont have any support-screen in the manifest. Wouldnt android render my layout-normal main.xml to the small format automatically? The emultaor did that just fine!

Comment: @arunsoorya: You are right, it must have been a small screen. The doc says: Caution: If all your resources use a size qualifier that is larger than the current screen, the system will not use them and your application will crash at runtime (for example, if all layout resources are tagged with the xlarge qualifier, but the device is a normal-size screen).